# string vector not getting properly assigned using set_union

Tags: c++

I think I'm lacking some basic understanding of assignment in C/C++ here!  I have a function that computes the set union between two string vectors.  The reason I do this is because the algorithm library's function `set_union` requires that both vectors are sorted first and if I do it the following way then I can't forget to sort:

```
vector<string> SetOperations::my_set_union(vector<string> set1,
                                            vector<string> set2) {
    sort(set1.begin(), set1.end());
    sort(set2.begin(), set2.end());

    vector<string> v;
    set_union(set1.begin(), set1.end(), set2.begin(), set2.end(), back_inserter(v));
    return v;
}
```

I then do the following:

```
vector<string> vec = set_ops.my_set_union(vec1, vec2);
```

where `vec1` and `vec2` are string vectors containing a single `"a"` and `"a"` each and `set_ops` is an instantiation of a class that I have these set operations in (like the one above).  They both definitely have these elements - I have printed the two vectors out.

For some (simple?) reason, `vec` ends up having a single element of `"a"` instead of two elements (`"a"` and `"a"`).

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?  Am I meant to a copy function or something?

Thank you :).

Comment: A set can only contain a single element one time.  What are you actually trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `merge` instead of `set_union`. `set_union` will eliminate similar enteries.

see [merge](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/merge/) and [set_union](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/set_union/) refrences.

Answer (score 2):

I think you've misunderstood what `set_union` is supposed to do.

It sounds like you want `std::merge` instead.

Answer (score 1):

If I remember my set theory well, that is what the union of two sets is. So it's expected behavior.

The reason is that a set cannot have duplicate elements. Since the union of two sets also produces a valid set, then it will only have a single `"a"` value.

Answer (score 0):

This is desired behavior, as mathematical sets do not contain duplicates. When you call set_union, it should remove duplicate elements (in this case your two cases of "a"). Try it on two vectors containing (respectively) ("a", "b"), and ("a", "c"). You should get a vector with just "a" back.